# How to add new instance of an object to an array of objects XCode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an array called ****imageCollection**** which contains all the photos on the device. I want to display these in a more robust way, for example as a photos collage on screen. In order to do this I have created a struct ***ImageObject*** which has additional properties like the x and y coordinates. I want to store a group of ***ImageObjects*** in an array **imageObjectGroup**, where each instance contains one image from my camera roll. Ultimately creating an instance of imageObject for each photo in my camera roll. I need help constructing this for loop that creates a new imageObjects instance. It can be found at the bottom of the function that populates imageCollection (array with all images from camera roll)

Code:

```
// Array containing all the images from camera roll
var imageCollection = [PHAsset]()

// Populating array with all images for loop is also here that adds each photo as a imageObjects instance
func getImages() {
    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: nil)
    assets.enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in
       // self.cameraAssets.add(object)
        imageCollection.append(object)
    })

    //In order to get latest image first, we just reverse the array
    imageCollection.reverse()
    
    // ADDING INSTANCES OF ‘imageObjectGroup’ HERE 
    for index in imageCollection{
        print(index);
    }
}

// The images array is where each photo instance will be stored
struct ImageObject: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let image = PHAsset()
    /// Card x position
    var x: CGFloat = 0.0
    /// Card y position
    var y: CGFloat = 0.0
    /// Card rotation angle
    var degree: Double = 0.0
}

var imageObjectGroup = [ImageObject]()
```

Comment: `let images = [PHAsset]()` shouldn't this be `let image = PHAsset()`?

Comment: You're right @aheze it should only be one instance of a photo, thank you I've edited the code to reflect this

Comment: Thanks. But where are you going to get the `x`, `y`, and `degree` values? If you can edit your code to show that, I can post an answer.

Comment: @aheze All of the coordinates / degree are defaulting to 0 during initialization. I have them because I plan to use them in case I spawn multiple photos and have them move around on screen but I plan to handle any changes in their values after initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
for phAsset in imageCollection {
    let newImageObject = ImageObject(image: phAsset) /// make a new `ImageObject` 
    imageObjectGroup.append(newImageObject) /// append it
}
```

or this one-liner:

```
imageObjectGroup = imageCollection.map { ImageObject(image: $0) }
```

...Just make sure to change `let image = PHAsset()` to `var image = PHAsset()`, otherwise you won't be able to change the image.

Comment: thank you, this worked perfectly. Not sure why this part confused me so much your answer makes it a lot simpler